# How to remove white color around Labelfield in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, labelfield

I am developing a blackberry app and I am new to Blackberry. I am using Label Field in every screens, but there is a color surrounding the LabelField other than the background I have given for the screen like the image I have given here..

[image]

This is a header in my App,which comes in every screens. Here you can see a white color around the "state editions". It does not look good. I want the orange background color at the place of white color. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Will you please post the code segment you use for the LabelField, normally it doesn't have any background (no white), and it has transpasernt background. Did you set any background for it via setBackground(params)?

Comment: Ignore previous comment - Will you please post the code segment you use for the LabelField, normally it doesn't have any background color. Did you set any background for it via setBackground(params)?

Comment: lF1= new LabelField("state editions",LabelField.FIELD_LEFT |FIELD_VCENTER)
        {
         public void paint(Graphics graphics)
            {
                graphics.clear(); 
                graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.ORANGE);
                graphics.fillRect(0, 0,0, 0);  
                super.paint(graphics);
            }      
        };

Comment: I have posted my comment in Answer (for long text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the following code.. (from your comment)

```java
lF1= new LabelField("state editions",LabelField.FIELD_LEFT |FIELD_VCENTER) {
    public void paint(Graphics graphics) { 
        graphics.clear();
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
        graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.ORANGE); graphics.fillRect(0, 0,0, 0); 
        super.paint(graphics); 
    } 
};
```

Try to modify this like the following:

```java
lF1= new LabelField("state editions",LabelField.FIELD_LEFT |FIELD_VCENTER) {
    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {             
        super.paint(graphics); 
    } 
};
```

That means, you don't have to extend default `LabelField`.

Just use,

```java
lF1= new LabelField("state editions",LabelField.FIELD_LEFT |FIELD_VCENTER);
```

And check the `Graphics` , `graphics.clear()` etc in the API.

Comment: Use `lF1.setFont(desiredFont)`. Changing font color requires extending `LabelField`. You just have to add `graphics.setColor(desiredColor)` before calling `super.paint(graphics)`.